# how to keep an image the same size in any html4 browser, and map out clickable parts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html4

I have a sun with rays that are off to angles.  The Sun.jpg shouldn't be bigger or smaller and should fit inside an html element of the screen.
outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html  can do this in html5 but what about old school html4. i tested it and it did not work

(sorry im more of a C++,c#,TSQL developer)

what would be the code to do both.  its very confusing out there with html5, google api's, and need to make sure if seen on a phone, the mappings still are effective. (newer phones of course)

```
   <map id="imgmap201412311375" name="imgmap201412311375">
   <area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="405,3,469,23" href="" target="" />
   <area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="430,22,499,42" href="" target="" />
   <area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="456,45,529,65" href="" target="" />
   <area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="483,67,563,91" href="" target="" />
   <area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="518,93,597,116" href="" target="" />
   <area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="551,119,626,141" href="" target="" />
   <area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="584,143,655,165" href="" target="" />
   <area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="615,167,687,188" href="" target="" />
   <area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="642,191,717,212" href="" target="" />
   <area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="672,215,744,230" href="" target="" />
   <area shape="rect" alt="Real Estate" title="Real Estate" coords="700,232,735,248" href="http://www.arubaadvisors.com/Home/Real-Estate" target="_self" />
  </map>

    <img width="100%" src="http://www.arubaadvisors.com/sun.jpg" usemap="#imgmap201412311375" />
```

the size of the picture is adjusted no matter what browser, but the mappings fail.

Comment: You could either just define the width and height of the element, or figure the percentages. What have you tried is the real question

Comment: hello, do you have some code to show ? Do you talk about image map and clickable area, or just a background-image ? sorry if it is not clear to me :)

Comment: if it has to be a background image for this to work in html4 that fine. the code has been added above.  But i still dont know if my code  will keep sun.jpg the correct size for the resolution of a browser.  on top of the task i have to map out clickable areas on rays of a sun that have words on them that come from all different angles

Comment: I feel like i'm in the 90's again...

Comment: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html

can do it